# euca2ools for Windows/Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cygwin, eucalyptus

Is there any way to use euca2ools natively on Windows or through Cygwin or is there any other tool compatible with eucalyptus  which I could run under Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with Eucalyptus, e.g. for EC2:

```
aws --endpoint-url http://myeuca:8773/services/Eucalyptus ec2 describe-instances
```

the example assumes you have already [configured credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).